# Align Y Axis Ticks in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have plotted two [Graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlEB9.jpg) with matplotlib. I want to align the y axis ticks, so that the left hand side of each graph aligns.

I am trying yaxis.set_ticks_position() but with no success.

What is the correct command to use?

Comment: The axes size changes due to the use of `tight_layout` or `constrained_layout`. If that is not what you want to need to remove those commands from your code.

Comment: Thanks. Is there is a command or mitigation within tight_layout that I can apply to stop this happening?

Comment: No. That's in principle the idea of tight_layout, to change the positions of things such that they fit nicely. However, if you were producing your two plots as subplots in a single figure, you would get the desired alignment for free.